# How to parse this response from Easyship webhook

Tags: php

I'm working with Easyship and trying to parse the response from their webhook when the status of an order changes. Firstly I had trouble even receiving data, and tried the following:

```
print_r($_POST, TRUE)
print_r($_GET, TRUE)
print_r($_REQUEST, TRUE)
print_r(file_get_contents("php://input"), TRUE)
```

Only the last one receives any data. The data I receive is the following:

```
@"event_type":"shipment.tracking.checkpoints.created","resource_type":"shipment","resource_id":"ESHK25561976","tracking_status":{"easyship_shipment_id":"ESHK25561976","platform_order_number":"30","origin":"HK","destination":"HK","company_order_number":null,"status":"In Transit to Customer","tracking_number":"SF1042689716516","tracking_page_url":"https://www.trackmyshipment.co/shipment-tracking/ESHK25561976","checkpoints":[{"order_number":1,"handler":"SF Express Local","message":null,"location":null,"city":null,"country_name":"Hong Kong","country_iso3":"HKG","state":null,"postal_code":null,"checkpoint_time":"2020-10-16T17:47:10.802Z","primary_status":"Pending Pickup Confirmation",@"order_number":2,"handler":"SF Express Local","message":"Your package has been prepared and is awaiting pickup from SF Express Local","location":null,"city":null,"country_name":"Hong Kong","country_iso3":"HKG","state":null,"postal_code":null,"checkpoint_time":"2020-10-16T18:00:55.285Z","primary_status":"Awaiting Scan from Courier",@"order_number":101,"handler":"Sf Express","message":"【Hong Kong】 S.F. Express has picked up the shipment","location":"Hong Kong","city":"Hong Kong","country_name":null,"country_iso3":null,"state":null,"postal_code":null,"checkpoint_time":"2020-10-19T14:45:47.000Z","primary_status":"In Transit to Customer",@"order_number":102,"handler":"Sf Express","message":"【Hong Kong】 Shipment transiting to next station","location":"Hong Kong","city":"Hong Kong","country_name":null,"country_iso3":null,"state":null,"postal_code":null,"checkpoint_time":"2020-10-19T17:31:46.000Z","primary_status":"In Transit to Customer",@"order_number":103,"handler":"Sf Express","message":"【Hong Kong】 Shipment arrive at Hong Kong distribution center","location":"Hong Kong","city":"Hong Kong","country_name":null,"country_iso3":null,"state":null,"postal_code":null,"checkpoint_time":"2020-10-19T20:37:59.000Z","primary_status":"In Transit to Customer"]}}
```

I'm not sure how I can parse this to extract the information I need. I have tried using a combination of json_decode and parse_str to no avail.

Any tips?

Comment: From the looks of it, it should be a JSON string. Did you by any chance removed any part of the string that made it an invalid JSON?

Comment: No, this is the raw response I'm getting - starting with "@"

Comment: I would say recheck the webhook documentation. Most webhooks should return JSON nowadays. Something else could be wrong.

Comment: Did you ever get a resolution on this? It looks like easyship bugged their api server or something. Vlam is correct that easyship should (and usually does) only send JSON content with their webhook posts. It's also possible that this is being injected from elsewhere in your codebase, or somehow by your web server, etc. Hard to be sure without being able to follow the code and do some debugging. I've had easyship integrations going for a couple years using webhooks daily and haven't come across this.